# Spring 4.2.3 with Hibernate validator 5.2.2.Final does not work

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I am trying to integration Spring 4.2.3 with hibernate validator v.5.2.2.Final to validate input JSON data expose with REST Controller.
I don't see any compile time or running time exception but at the same time it does not validate input data.

Pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- jsr303 validation dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-cdi</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Pojo java class:

```
    public class RequestVO {    

    @NotEmpty
    private String testValidation;

    @NotNull
    private String testNull;

    @NotBlank
    private String testBlank;

   .... getters and setters .....
}

    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/user")
    public @ResponseBody  ResponseVO getLoginResponse(@Valid @RequestBody RequestVO request, Errors error) {

            ResponseVO response = new ResponseVO ();


    if (error.hasErrors()) {
            System.err.println("Success");
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code gives you some errors? put it here.

Comment: No it does not. Here is my json request {
        "testNull":""
 
}

Comment: it does not validate the request.

Answer (score 3):

In your dependency list there's a comment saying *...jsr303 validation dependencies...*. Note the bean validation has an updated specification ([JSR-349](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/)), and this can very well be your issue.

You should align your dependencies in the following manner

```
hibernate-validator-5.x.x 
validation-api-1.1.x
```

which implement [JSR-349](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/)

OR

```
hibernate-validator-4.x.x
validation-api-1.0.x.
```

which implements [JSR-303](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/)

If you mix the dependencies, the validation will simply not kick-in. As a solution suggestion, add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

and make sure that you remove any dependency to `validation-api-1.0` jar

Comment: I added                                                                                                        '<dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
         <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
  </dependency>' it did not work

Comment: I tried both with versions. Still not able to do validation.

Comment: Make sure that you use `@EnableWebMvc` or `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` depending whether you use java or xml config

Answer (score 0):

I think is interest to take a look at this [link](http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/017-validate-spring-rest-webservice-request/)

and if you to remove the validation just remove `@Valid` from method and you're ok.

Comment: I am not able to follow instruction, can you please elaborate?